# Are there any JavaScript libraries for defining keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript page in which I want to add shortcuts like.. for 't' it will do something and different functions for different commands.

I can implement this using a stack and event listener.

Is there any open source framework that does the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [`Mousetrap`](http://craig.is/killing/mice). Take a look at the following example code:

```
Mousetrap.bind('t', function() {
    // do something
});
```

It also supports combinations:

```
Mousetrap.bind(['command+k', 'ctrl+k'], function(e) {
    // do something
}
```